# Post request with many params in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to do post request on python, with much params. I have one key 'name' and many many values. I tried using the `requests` library. The request should be like this:

```
requests.post('http://mysite.cc/name=val1&name=val2&name=val3')
```

There are more than 100 values for `name`. The documentation says I can send a dict with `params`, like `{'name': 'val1', 'name': 'val2', 'name': 'val3'}`. But I really don't understand how to create a `dict` with one key `name` and list of values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a *list* for the values:

```
params = {'name': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']}

response = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

and they'll be added to the URL as `name=val1&name=val2&name=val3`.

Note that the `params` argument is to specify *URL parameters*, the part of the URL after the `?` question mark. This is usually used in a *GET* request, although you can use it with a POST as well.

If you needed to send the parameters in the POST body as a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  body, use `data` instead:

```
params = {'name': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']}

response = requests.post(url, data=params)
```

Demo with http://httpbin.org:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> params = {'name': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']}
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/get'
>>> response = requests.get(url, params=params)
>>> pprint(response.json())
{u'args': {u'name': [u'val1', u'val2', u'val3', u'val4']},
 u'headers': {u'Accept': u'*/*',
              u'Accept-Encoding': u'gzip, deflate, compress',
              u'Connection': u'close',
              u'Host': u'httpbin.org',
              u'User-Agent': u'python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.6 Darwin/13.2.0',
              u'X-Request-Id': u'2fb6d325-308a-4669-a791-73666ac0d298'},
 u'origin': u'84.92.98.170',
 u'url': u'http://httpbin.org/get?name=val1&name=val2&name=val3&name=val4'}
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> response = requests.post(url, data=params)
>>> pprint(response.json())
{u'args': {},
 u'data': u'',
 u'files': {},
 u'form': {u'name': [u'val1', u'val2', u'val3', u'val4']},
 u'headers': {u'Accept': u'*/*',
              u'Accept-Encoding': u'gzip, deflate, compress',
              u'Connection': u'close',
              u'Content-Length': u'39',
              u'Content-Type': u'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              u'Host': u'httpbin.org',
              u'User-Agent': u'python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.6 Darwin/13.2.0',
              u'X-Request-Id': u'473e4e2d-e125-45b8-9697-b93b23ec2eca'},
 u'json': None,
 u'origin': u'84.92.98.170',
 u'url': u'http://httpbin.org/post'}
```